# View not updating model on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a view to display the groups that a logged in member is assigned to. Roles correspond to email groups in this case.

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentityRole>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Emails";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div class="bg-primary panel-body text-center"><h4>Email Groups</h4></div>

<div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-bordered">
    <tr><th>Email Group</th><th>Assigned</th><th></th></tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="4" class="text-center">No Email Groups Present</td></tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var role in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@role.Name</td>
            @if (User.IsInRole(role.Name))
            {
                <td>Yes</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No</td>
            }
            <td class="text-center">
                <form asp-action="ManageDelete" asp-route-id="@role.Id" method="post">
                    @if (!User.IsInRole(role.Name))
                    {
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" asp-action="ManageEdit" asp-route-id="@role.Id">Add Me To This Group</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button type="submit" asp-action="ManageDelete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"asp-route-id="@role.Id">Delete Me From Group</button>
                    }
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

In my controller, I have a method for allowing users to delete themselves from a group:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ManageDelete(string id)
        {
            AppUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            IdentityResult result;

            if(user != null)
            {
                result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    AddErrorsFromResult(result);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ManageIndex");
        }
```

However, when the above View is refreshed from this action method, it doesn't display the correct information. I've checked and the roles are updated corrected in the database. If I stop debugging and restart, the View then shows the correct info.

How can I refresh the View to display the correct information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role claims are stored inside authentication cookie. So, calling RemoveFromRoleAsync won't remove the claims from the current cookie.

You still need to regenerate the cookie, if you want to see the changes right away.

```
result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);    
await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
```